# IP filtering on a router

Tags: networking, router, ip

I enabled IP filtering on my Siemens ADSL SL2-141 router, and added a single rule blocking Google's homepage address 212.179.180.117:

[image]

But, it seems to have no effect: I can still access this IP address from my browser.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I changed the settings based on the answers, but it still doesn't work:

[image]

I have the exact same settings for the "inbound" direction.

Even when I access the IP adddress directly as http : // 65.55.206.228, it is still not blocked.

EDIT: Here is the traceroute:

```
$ traceroute 65.55.206.228
traceroute to 65.55.206.228 (65.55.206.228), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  SL2141.siemens (10.0.0.138)  1.577 ms  2.199 ms  2.797 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

EDIT: I now noticed that the link http : // 65.55.206.228 hangs in Chrome and Lynx (as expected), but it does open on Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here.

1. You have the traffic direction set to "inbound", whereas if you want
   to block traffic to an external address, you should set it to
   outbound.
2. You are using the external address as both the source and
   destination (as pointed out by Errol).  The source should be set to
   `0.0.0.0` to match all internal addresses
3. The "home page" of Google resides on thousands of servers worldwide,
   and targetting a single IP address is unlikely to be effective.  If
   you were able to determine all of their server IP addresses today,
   it is unlikely that this would work for very long, as they change
   their infrastruture all the time.  If you are trying to block access
   to `http://*.google.com`, you would need to target the DNS names, and
   you would need a more sophisticated firewall to do this, or a proxy
   server.

Comment: I changed the settings (see the updated question) but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Could you add a traceroute to the question:  `tracert 65.66.206.228`

Comment: Done. It seems that traceroute cannot find the address.

Comment: Your router is blocking traceroute getting there.  So by what method are you able to get to it?

Comment: I can get to "http : // 65.55.206.228 " only on Firefox (not on Chrome nor Lynx)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't cached?  Does it still work if you start private browsing?  What extensions are installed?  It sounds like the site is being blocked, so something is specifically happning with ff that makes it look like it isn't.

Comment: The site doesn't load in a private browsing window. This indeed seems like a cache, but what cache can follow links and open articles that did not even exist when I blocked the IP address?!

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Do you have any extensions installed that might contribute?  A tor proxy perhaps, or any other form of proxy?

Comment: My Firefox is set to "No proxy", and all my addons and extensions are related to multimedia only...

Comment: Perhaps firefox has cached a redirect or something.  Have you cleared the cache?  I am just guessing now, it is extremely unlikely that ff is bypassing the firewall, it is just appearing to.  What it might be using to do that is difficult to tell without looking at it.

Comment: I cleared the cache and indeed now the IP address is not accessible. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the source IP to whatever your host IP is, for example, `192.168.1.2`, otherwise this won't do anything.

Comment: I changed the source to ALL (see my updated question) and this still doesn't work..